# Handle resource versioning with require.js

Tags: versioning, requirejs

We are planning on versioning our key resources at build time by appending a version to the filename (e.g. main-v1_1.js)

We are learning how to use require.js to manage our resource loading. I would like to be able to specify a postfix in the require.js configuration that will be appended to the resources being loaded.

```
var version = "1_1";  //inserted at build time
requirejs.config(
   {
      postfix: "_" + version  //is there something like this?
   }
);
require([main]...); //would load main_1_1.js
```

Suggestions? Thoughts? Better ways to handle this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the urlArgs parameter to append a version querystring.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this would be suited [to the map configuration option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map).

```
requirejs.config({
    map: {
        'some/newmodule': {
            'foo': 'foo1.2'
        },
        'some/oldmodule': {
            'foo': 'foo1.0'
        }
    }
});
```

> When 'some/newmodule' does `require('foo')` it will get the foo1.2.js
>   file, and when 'some/oldmodule' does `require('foo')` it will get the
>   foo1.0.js file. This feature only works well for scripts that are real
>   AMD modules that call define() and register as anonymous modules.

Comment: I can see this working if the mapping could accept wildcards ('*': { '*': '*_1_1') for the actual script files themselves and not just the module. I don't want to have to map every js file...